# Magento 2 no css/js loaded after setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, css, language, static-content

Magento is searching for files into below location,(one for example)

```
localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/it_CH/mage/calendar.css
```

but after I run `setup:static-content:deploy` in `pub/static/frontend`. I only have `en_US`. I have added no other languages so I don't know why magento is looking into `it_CH` returning 404.

Comment: Please, check the current language in `STORES > Configuration`?

Comment: Thank you. But i still don't understand the logic behind this, in backend everything works normally and look for files into en_US so i can run setup:static-content:deploy with no options. In frontend i need to specify my language? And if i have more than one language i need to run the command for every one?

Comment: Yes, you should read more: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run deploy command like below to prevent error from it_CH store,

**For multi language store, you have to pass each language as space separated after deploy command**

In your case **it_CH** language is enabled, so you have to run below command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US it_CH
```

If have problem to deploy, add memory, It work for me with Plesk

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US it_CH
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute deploy command with each language pack and provide permission to pub and var folder

Steps you need to follow-

- move to var folder using command `cd var`
- now remove old file using `rm -rf *`
- now go to static folder present in pub directory and execute `rm -rf
  *`
- Finally execute deploy

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US it_CH

- Now execute permission commands

  chmod -R 755 pub var

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has been struggling with this as I have here was the root I took to combat this error successfully.

1. Ensure mod_rewrite is enable on your server
2. Clear all caches
3. Run the php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command
4. then chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/

IF these still fail (As they did me);

1. Ensure the apache module mod_version is installed on the server.

Why? Because in the Pub folder there is a htaccess file that is using the IfVersion commands. You have to have mod_version installed for apache to understand this.

As soon as I enabled this, boom all started working as should.